# Why does php command line work differently than making the file executable

Tags: php, bash, command-line, file-get-contents, chmod

I'm using linux command line. Why does code below work when I type `php myfile.php` but not when I type `./myfile.php`. I've chmodded the file to be executable. I simply get the error `: No such file or directory`. Any suggestions?

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

$json = file_get_contents('./myjson.json', TRUE);

$obj = json_decode($json);
var_dump($obj);


?>
```

Comment: Do you have `/usr/bin/env`?

Comment: ENCOM_OS-12# ls /usr/bin/env
/usr/bin/env - So yes, it exists. And other php scripts work.